# supertest nodejs test get call

Tags: node.js, supertest

I'm building an API and I'm trying to test it with mocha and supertest.

I'm correctly testing a POST call with this code:

```
it("Should generate a PDF based on the given data using API", function(done) {

    request(app)
    .post("/api/document/print")
    .send({tplName: "default", tplData: { title: "Testee", p1: "paragraph"}})
    .expect(200, done);

});
```

But when I try to test a GET request with this code:

```
it("Should get HTML of the selected template", function(done) {

    request(app)
    .get("/api/template/default/html")
    .expect(200, done);

});
```

The test fails, if I run my app and try it in Chrome I get the correct response (200).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. What does the test say when it fails?

Comment: well.. nothing. it just fails.

Comment: Your tests aren't giving you *any* output?

Comment: `npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.` but above there's nothing.

Comment: What's your `scripts.test` command in package.json (and, if it's `make test`, what's `test` in your Makefile)?

Comment: the command is `mocha tests/`

Comment: Do you have a `test/mocha.opts` file, and if so what is its content?

Answer (score 0):

Are these tests in the same file? Within the same describe block? Perhaps you could try this:

`.expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        done()
      });`

Comment: @FezVrasta, why don't you try calling done outside of the expect call